# Share one app on different hosts

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

We have configured multiple hosts, every host has a different ROOT-App

```
<Host name="domain1"  appBase="webapps_domain1" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
<Host name="domain2"  appBase="webapps_domain2" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
```

but we have one application which should be available on every host, is it possible without running multiple instances of it?

Comment: An alternative is [Host Name Aliases](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases)

Comment: This will not work with two different ROOT Applications

Comment: For now a added a reverse proxy in apache